# Take a single value from a MySQL field and store it in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner to PHP and MySql. What I wish to do is take a single field value from a MySql table and store it into a php variable. I tried this code but it does not seem to work:

```
//Get Role ID

$con=     mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","darrenvellaedp2");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT userRoleID FROM tbl_users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['userRoleID'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: "does not seem to work" --- is not a good issue explanation. The same way as "fix it somehow" isn't a good answer for it.

Comment: Error messages? Wrong output? What exactly "does not seem to work"?

Comment: SORRY I forgot to say that it did not echo anything. Im very sorry my bad/ I'm trying to get it to echo the user ID to confirm that it is working but it is not echoing anything.

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: I'm not getting any errors from php or MySQL. It's just no echoing anything. Ofcourse it's not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//make the connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","darrenvellaedp2") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
//create the query
$result = "SELECT userRoleID FROM tbl_users" or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
//execute the query
$res = $con->query($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    //this will print the userroleid out to the screen
    echo $row['userRoleID'];
    //this will store it in a variable
    $UserRoleID = $row['userRoleID'];
}
```

It would have been easier for you to just google it as there's a whole section about this on [PHP.NET](http://php.net)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. However I'm still getting an error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fecth_array()

Comment: @user3136576 I've just edited my answer, it was my mistake I accidentally spelled "fetch" wrong, I put "fecth" try it now

Comment: Sorry for not noticing that myself. Thanks buddy it worked :)